# Como exibir um textView de uma Activity em outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Valor do Alcool"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Valor da Gasolina"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtAlcool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtGasolina"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalcular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Enviar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Valor do Alcool"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Valor da Gasolina"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtAlcool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtGasolina"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalcular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Enviar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Gostaria que o resultado de tvResultado mostrasse em outra actvity.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta colocando o código utilizado para chamar a segunda Acitivy e para recuperar o texto.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de passar informações entre duas Activities.

Uma destas formas é utilizar a própria `Intent` que invoca a segunda `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("chave", "texto");
startActivity(it);
```

Para recuperar na sua segunda `Activity` seria:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstancestate) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    //Pega a intent que disparou esta Activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //Recuperei o texto
    String texto = intent.getStringExtra("chave");
}
```

Outra forma seria utilizar [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=pt-br#pref). Você irá precisar definir o nome do arquivo a ser compartilhado:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "shareData";
```

Na sua primeira Activity você guarda um valor assim:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("chave", texto).commit();
```

Na segunda Activity recupere a informação assim:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String texto = sharedPreferences.getString("chave");
```

*PS*: Não importa como deseja armazenar o valor de PREFS_NAME mas ele tem que ser o mesmo em ambas as Activitys.

Comment: Já fiz isso, não deu certo.

Comment: Edita a pergunta e põe o código utilizado para chamar a segunda Acitivy e para recuperar o texto.

Comment: Percebi um erro ao utilizar o SharedPreferences, faltava utilizar o `.commit()` no método de `putString()`